# Find PID by searching for a process keyword

Tags: cmd, windows-server-2008, pid, taskmanager

In Task Manager, I find several processes that are running, the process description is mostly not short on the server and its sometimes difficult to identify a process based on the description.

Is there a script through which we can search for the PID by searching for a keyword in the description. Eg: searching for keyword "weblogic"

Answer (score 0):

You can use below command to find out weblogic process pid by using port on windows:

netstat -ano|find /i "7001"

Where 7001 is weblogic port.
Check the last column of output for pid

Comment: I have more than 1 weblogic running on a single server. They don't use the same port. That's why I'm trying to know how to search based on description. They all share the same image name and user. Therefore for my task I need to search based on description